# Testing regexes in Python using py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, pytest

Regexes are still something of a dark art to me, but I think that's one of those things that just takes practice.  As such, I'm more concerned with being able to produce py.test functions that show me where my regexes are failing.  My current code is something like this:

```
my_regex = re.compile("<this is where the magic (doesn't)? happen(s)?>")

def test_my_regex():
    tests = ["an easy test that I'm sure will pass",
             "a few things that may trip me up",
             "a really pathological, contrived example",
             "something from the real world?"]

    test_matches = [my_regex.match(test) for test in tests]

    for i in range(len(tests)):
        print("{}: {!r}".format(i, tests[i]))
        assert test_matches[i] is not None
```

for which the output when I run `py.test myfile.py` is something like

```
0: "an easy..."
1: "a few things..."
2: "a really pathological..."
```

where the last one is the first (only?) one to have not passed the test.

I suppose I could do something like an

```
assertSequenceEqual(test_matches, [not None]*len(test_matches))
```

but that seems gross, and I was under the impression that `<object> is not None` is the preferred way of checking that an object isn't `None` rather than `<object> != None`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another approach is to use [parametrize](https://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html).

```
my_regex = re.compile("<this is where the magic (doesn't)? happen(s)?>")

@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_str', [
    "an easy test that I'm sure will pass",
    "a few things that may trip me up",
    "a really pathological, contrived example",
    "something from the real world?",
])
def test_my_regex(test_str):
     assert my_regex.match(test_str) is not None
```

This will produce an independent test case for each test string. This IMO is cleaner, easier to add new cases and also has the advantage of allowing each `test_str` to fail individually without affecting the others.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `all`:

```
assert all([my_regex.match(test) for test in goodinputs])
```

You might also want to test inputs that should NOT match, and test those with a negated `any`.

```
assert not any([my_regex.match(test) for test in badinputs])
```

If you want to see which matches fail, you could reorganise your existing code slightly, something like:

```
for test in tests:
    assert my_regex.match(test), test
```

which should print out the value of `test` if the assertion fails.

However, this will only print out the details of the first failure.

If you want to see *all* failures, you could do:

```
failures = [test for test in tests if not my_regex.match(test)]
assert len(failures) == 0, failures
```

Comment: That's helpful, but part of what I'd like is for py.test to print which matches fail, and it doesn't seem to be doing that yet.

Comment: I've run into another couple of problems:
1. In another section of code, I added a Python3 print statement with an end=" ", which causes Py.test to complain about that being an error and not running further tests.
2. Before, tests were taking ~30 seconds, which seemed long.  Now it's been running for about 10 minutes and still hasn't finished even though this is on a 2010 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Presumably that is a separate problem? If so, I suggest you start a new question rather that dealing with it in comments here.

Comment: You're right, but I didn't want to seem rude and ungrateful by not responding.